# Raspberry Pi NAS Server Which Is Also Accessible Via USB

Tags: storage, raid

I am planning to build a raid NAS server using my Raspberry Pi and going to use the tutorial found [here](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/build-a-raspberry-pi-nas).

Is there a way how I can access the storage either through USB or the internet?

More specifically:

1. Storage should be accessible through the network client must be connected to the WiFi network
2. Storage should also be accessible through USB, client computer can connect to the server Raspberry Pi through something like a USB cable. Here the client computer doesn’t need to be connected to the WiFi network

Comment: I presume you mean that you want to be able to connect a computer to a USB port and access it as if it were a hard drive.  For that you need a model with a workable USB OTG port, either the Zero or the 4.  Beware that USB is *not symmetrical* and so this is not something that can be done with a normal port.

Comment: @goldilocks The OP wants to have a **N**etwork **A**ttached **S**torage so using an USB OTG connection makes less sense in my opinion.

Comment: O_o? So you think the OP means *"Can I attach a storage device to the pi via USB?"*   Makes sense (I know what NAS stands for, BTW, that is why I got my first pi!), just seems like a very odd question to have to ask for help with, particularly since at the top of the linked tutorial is a large, unambiguous picture of a Pi with several USB drives clearly attached...

Comment: Add more information. Your question is not clear enough. What do you mean by "*access the storage either through USB*"? Is it about the drives you would like to connect to the pi?

Comment: Sorry the question wasn’t clear - @goldilocks is correct, I’m trying to create setup where client can connect to server with a cable such as a USB cable

Answer (score 0):

You can just connect the RasPi to your local area network with an ethernet cable or wireless and install a file server on the RasPi. Most common file server programs are **NFS**, mainly used for Unix systems, and **Samba**, mainly used for MS Windows systems. Then you are able to remotely connect to NFS exports, or to network shares from Samba on the NAS. If you want to connect to the NAS from the internet as you asked, then there is some more effort needed to have a secure encrypted connection. In general you have to configure **port forwarding** on your internet router to redirect the outside traffic from the router to the RasPi so you can access the NAS from the internet.

Comment: `sshfs` is a fairly common choice too, I think.